# What are the potential drawbacks of deploying Gyroscope on IIS and SQL Server?

Tags: gyroscope-framework

The recommended hosting stack for a Gyroscope application is Linux, Nginx/Apache, PHP, MySQL. What are the drawbacks of running Gyroscope on IIS and Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gyroscope is written in PHP. So any dynamic web server that can run PHP would work. IIS can be extended to run PHP via ISAPI. The server can be optimized so that the performance and reliability is on par with Nginx or Apache.

Gyroscope comes with a collection of interchangeable database connectors. They are in the "connectors" folder in a fresh download (read: before deployment). Note that these files are not created equal. When a Gyroscope application is written for MySQL, one cannot simply change sql.php.mysql with sql.php.mssql. This is because MySQL and MSSQL has syntax differences.

As a framework, Gyroscope provides places for you to program the database interface. It works with any database or logical data storage such as a RESTful API. SQL databases are similar enough so it is tempting to "port" the code. In fact, most of the code can run without any changes. The code generator takes care of 90% of the cases. The main incompatibility is how records are paginated. In MySQL, "limit 10,10" returns the 10th to the 19th records. The syntax in MSSQL is more convoluted, and has to be written differently.

Unless a .NET application needs to co-exist on the server, there is little reason why IIS should be used. Gyroscope, or any PHP implementation, works better with the boost of HHVM and HAProxy.